# javascript and knockout combobox

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, combobox

I have a jquery ui combo box that uses a hidden dropdownlist to update the knockout objects.  If I display the dropdownlist the knockout object is updated appropriately was I change the value.  If I change the combobox value the dropdown changes to reflect this but the knockout object is not changed whatsoever.  The changesubgroup is never called even though the dropdownlist's value changes.  I need it to fire the changesubgroup event.

```
       EmployerGroupModel.prototype.ChangeSubGroup = function () {
    try {
        if (this.CurrentSubGroupValue()) {
            var tempGroupsResults;
            var updateCurrentSubGroup = false;
            var len = this.SubGroupsResults().length - 1;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (this.CurrentSubGroup() != undefined)
                {
                    if (this.CurrentSubGroup().EMPL_GRP_DTL_KY != undefined) {
                        if (this.SubGroupsResults()[i].EMPL_GRP_DTL_KY == this.CurrentSubGroup().EMPL_GRP_DTL_KY) {
                            if (this.SubGroupsResults()[i] != this.CurrentSubGroup())
                            {
                                tempGroupsResults = this.SubGroupsResults().filter(this.ExcludeFilter);
                                tempGroupsResults.push(this.CurrentSubGroup());
                                this.SubGroupsToUpdate.push(this.CurrentSubGroup());
                                updateCurrentSubGroup = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var myObject = this.SubGroupsResults().filter(this.ArrayFilter)[0];
            if (updateCurrentSubGroup)
            {
                this.SubGroupsResults(this.tempGroupsResults());
            }
            this.CurrentSubGroup(myObject);
        }

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.toString());
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is totally answering your question but maybe you need a custom binding? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

here is one I did for an autocomplete should be fairly similar to a combobox.

https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/26/

so here is the binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element,valueAccessor, allBindings);
         var source = allBindings.get('autocompleteOptions');
         var sourceUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(source);
          $(element).autocomplete({
             source: sourceUnwrapped,
             select: function( event, ui ) {
             var value = valueAccessor();
             value(ui.item.value);
                    }
          });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       var value = valueAccessor();
       ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element,valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

I used the jquery ui autocomplete and set it up in the init portion of the custom handler. it takes an  array that I called autocomplete options.

here is the html to use it.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags2">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags2" data-bind="autocomplete: tags2, autocompleteOptions: availableTags ">
</div>
```

here is the whole thing if you don't want to go to the fiddle to see it. you can start typing in the input to get the autocomplete. clicking on one updates the knockout value (the label below) you can also add more items to the autocomplete list by use the textbox and add button

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element,valueAccessor, allBindings);
         var source = allBindings.get('autocompleteOptions');
         var sourceUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(source);
          $(element).autocomplete({
             source: sourceUnwrapped,
             select: function( event, ui ) {
             var value = valueAccessor();
             value(ui.item.value);
                    }
          });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       var value = valueAccessor();
       ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element,valueAccessor);
    }
};



function model() {
  var self = this;
 this.tags2 = ko.observable("BASIC")
 this.newTag = ko.observable("");
 this.availableTags = ko.observableArray([
   "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme",
      "Prepositions are not real"
 ]);
 this.add = function(){
  self.availableTags.push(self.newTag());
 }
};

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);


    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: myViewModel.availableTags(),
      select: function( event, ui ) {
       myViewModel.tags(ui.item.value);
      }
    });

});
```

and here is the html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags2">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags2" data-bind="autocomplete: tags2, autocompleteOptions: availableTags ">
</div>
<br/>
you chose <span data-bind="text:tags2"></span>
<br/>
<p>
Add something to the autocomplete list: <input data-bind="textInput: newTag"/>
<button data-bind="click: add" >
+
</button>
</p>
```